# Embedding an html page inside Flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

Ok, I have managed to create a flask page that shows a bokeh image -- now I have to somehow put that into a template

https://gist.github.com/cloudformdesign/a0c5f2e8558ea3b60f0a

What I would like is to create a webpage with a few text boxes where the user can type the data they want to graph and it will be graphed below the text boxes. The user can select new data they want graphed and the graph will update.

I am very bad at coding in html, so I am very bad in creating templates. How would I do something like this?

## I created my own example, thanks to @elyase

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed/simple

This is a very simple example of embedding bokeh pages in an html page. The example giving by @elyase was helpful, but didn't actually work with python3 (I could not import or install pyaudio). It was also overly complicated for what I was trying to ask. The gist above gives a very simple answer with only two files, all in the same directory. Thanks a ton!

Comment: OK, so where is your code for the Flask apart from template?

Comment: there isn't any! That's all the code it takes to get a bokeh graph

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed/spectrogram)

Comment: @GarrettLinux, ah OK. So you have a library to plot the graph and want to show the image in the template?

Comment: elyase, that was exactly what I was looking for! Unfortunately it didn't work, but I took it as a learning example and wrote my own. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to create a view which will serve as static image, and you get the image url from that route.

I haven't got your included library so I'm going to use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org) and [numpy](http://www.numpy.org) to simulate what you are trying to attempt. This isn't a FULL solution for you (it's in the simplest working way using 2 views and 1 simple template), but you should be able to understand all the ESSENTIAL techniques which let you finish off your page.
I have a few comments and guidelines, and I think the code itself is pretty much self explanatory.

OK, here is the view **main.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/plot/')
def plot():
    try:
        # try to get the query string like ?width=xxx&height=xxx
        height = int(request.args.get('height'))
        width = int(request.args.get('width'))
    except ValueError:
        # if height, width not available, set a default value
        height, width = 100, 100
    # I randomly generate the plot which just based on H x W
    # you should be able to generate yours from your library
    to_draw = np.random.randint(0, 255, (height, width))
    img = plt.imshow(to_draw)
    # you can convert the graph to arrays and save to memory
    imgIO = StringIO()
    img.write_png(imgIO, noscale=True) # save to memory
    imgIO.seek(0)
    # and send that image as file as static file of url
    # like... /plot/?width=100&height=100
    return send_file(imgIO, mimetype='image/png')

# this is the main page with the form and user input
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # set the default values
    height, width = 100, 100
    # handle whenever user make a form POST (click the Plot button)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            # use this to get the values of user input from the form
            height = int(request.form['height'])
            width = int(request.form['width'])
        except ValueError:
            pass
    # and pass the context back to the template
    # if no form is POST, default values will be sent to template        
    return render_template('index.html', height=height, width=width)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

And the template at **templates/index.html**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Micro Plot!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Interactive Plot</h1>
  <form action="/" name="plot" method="POST">
      <p><input type="text" name='height' value="{{ height }}" /></p>
      <p><input type="text" name='width' value="{{ width }}" /></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Plot Now!"></p>
  </form>
  <img src="{{ url_for('plot', height=height, width=width) }}" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The trick is to set the image src to send a GET request to the url, and then Flask's /plot/ view to render an in-memory image and feed back as static.

#### Key Notes:

The [url_for](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#url-building) will then dynamically generate the src as like `/plot/?width=xxx&height=xxx`.

To get the [querystring](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object) from the url in the view, use `request.args.get('KeyName')`.

Once your plot is ready, save it in the memory with Python [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) module and use Flask's [send_file](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/32/) to serve as static content.

You should read and learn more about [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/) and [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp), you cannot build something really amazing without having a good understanding of how these things work together.

I hope this helps you understand the underlying techniques, and Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, but this wasn't quite the answer I was looking for. I want to use Bokeh because it offers dynamic plots -- not just an image! Thanks for your answer, I'm going to continue to learn flask side by side with embedding plots, and this should help. I think I will also be using send_File to send people csv data.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up creating my own answer with the help of elyase, and the code was pulled into an example folder in the bokeh project. Check it out here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed/simple

Comment: Page not found :(

Comment: that was 7 years ago. Examples come and go. I changed the accepted answer to the above one.